# regex mandatory character within character class

Tags: regex

I'm having a bit of trouble creating this regular expression. I'm not sure how to make the `,` required but also be in an optional class.

`^[0-9]+[,[0-9]+]?$`

I'm trying to do:

- starts with number(s)
- optionally has

  - comma **AND**
  - additional number(s)

What I can't figure out is how to make the comma and 2nd set of numbers optional, but, if the second set of numbers exists then the comma is required.

Could someone explain how this would be done?

Comment: why did you just ask a question and then immediately delete it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613013/any-benefits-of-declaring-many-variables-using-var-once

Comment: @Doorknob b/c i found a duplicate that answered my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a group, denoted with a pair of parentheses:

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?$
```

The question mark quantifier then applies to the whole group, not just the previous atom.

Answer (score 0):

Very close. For the second part, you need "zero or one of", so `(,[:digit:]+)?`